# how to run large loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 900 job to done. Each job is to fetch data from external source and store in the database. If I run 200 job or less runs smooth but if I run more than 200 jobs, it shows following error message:

"Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

For this I am using PHP, mysql and the response from external source is in xml format.

**First Attempt:**
I have 900 id in the database, so collected into an array using php, then run a for loop, and in each loop, I tried to collect data from external source by providing the id but got above mentioned error.

**Second Attempt:**
Instead of using forloop, I used while loop but same error message appear.

**Third Attempt:**
Instead of collecting all the 900 id into an array, while fetching each id from database, I tried to collect information from external source but still same error.

(My final Code:)

```
$sql="select user_id from user_id_lists where user='temp'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 //code to fetch data from external source by providing each user_id 
//and then following response is collected.
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($request_url));
            if($xml){
            foreach($xml->Users->User as $resultt){

                $title=$resultt->UserProfile->Name;
                echo $title."<br/>";
            }
}
```

So far I understood, it is showing above mentioned error message because of long loop (900 records). There must be a way to run such long loop. Please guide me how to solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I would consider breaking the loop into segments, say 100 each. And use cron job to perform a segment, say every 2 minutes.

Comment: This might be a lot of reasons, you are saying you are fetching from external sources. This can be from that source too. How many requests it can handle or allowed to handle. Furthermore, it can be your own server issues too. I recommend you to check the server log. Also, try to send requests and fetch data in chunk wise.

Comment: Did you try increasing your memory limit?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_fetch_all()` and use `foreach` loop to loop through your result instead of fetching one row at a time.

Something like this

```
$sql="select user_id from user_id_lists where user='temp'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$result= mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $k => $v){
...
}
```